# Rewrite using .htaccess if query string is empty

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

Might be a quick question for someone but it's not an area I have a huge amount of knowledge in.

I want to rewrite a URL using .htaccess **if the query string is empty**:

```
http://mydomain.com/js/file.js?foo=
```

So it rewrites to something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/js/error.js
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=$
RewriteRule ^js/file.js$ /js/error.js [R=301,L]
```